# Is it okay to tell the preferred company that you have received other job offers?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer, human-resources, follow-up

I have recently applied to Company A. I have gone through the 1st and 2nd interview and everything seems to be going well. In the 2nd interview, the senior manager told me that HR would get back to me in a week. After a week, I haven't received any news, so I sent HR and the Senior Manager a follow up email asking for the status of my application. HR replied approximately 30 mins after I sent the email saying that they would email me the status of my application next week (meaning this week) by the latest and should I need any further information during the time, I can contact her.

Since my second interview with Company A, I kept applying for other jobs. I got 2 interviews with Company B and Company C and they both have offered me a job. I told them I will get back to them in a week because I need to consider the relocation, benefits, etc..

It's already Thursday and I haven't heard from the Company A. I emailed HR and asked about the status of my application this morning She hasn't replied.

Is it bad if I send another email to the Company A that would read something like this?

> Dear Hiring Manager,
>
> I was very excited about the Designer position after talking with Mr.
>   Senior Manager the other day.          It seems like a great fit for both of
>   us and I am eager to join your team!
>
> However, I have received other job offers which are competitive and I
>   am considering them.
>
> I would rather work for your company; can you tell me what the status
>   regarding my application?
>
> Am I a serious candidate for the position?
>
> (If so) Is there a way to move the hiring process along?
>
> I am happy to talk with you again this week (or sooner) if that would
>   help.
>
> Thanks for your consideration! I look forward to talking with you
>   again soon!

Is it too cocky? Because you see, I am in a really tight time frame at the moment and I don't want to end up losing all offers the offers on the table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: To put it short, it is fine. If you have a deadline for giving an answer to those other offers, you can communicate it to the HR.
However, your email might sound a bit "pushy" with all these questions
Maybe you can just explain the situation to the HR and ask whether they will be able to provide you with an answer before the given deadline (if no deadline then define one). And state that you would rather work for them but that you cannot afford denying offers without being certain that you will get the job. And a detail but in your email, you miss a "is":"what the status **is** regarding..."

Comment: Oh yeah this is just a draft I wrote :) Anyway, yeah great suggestion @Puzzled! I should probably ask them if they're able to provide me with an answer before the given deadline. Just like what you said! Thanks a lot tho, I also think the word I wrote is a bit cocky and pushy. Thanks heaps!

Comment: @Puzzled Do you think I should offers or explicitly say the number of offers I got?

Comment: I don't think it matters how many you received. What matters is the fact that you have to take a decision by the date X. And that if they don't take a decision soon enough, you won't be available anymore. It is not about putting pressure on them, but rather about informing them of your constraints. Glad if I could help :)

Comment: @Puzzled you are indeed more than just a help! If I could, I wanted to treat you a posh evening tea :)

Comment: Hi @GoldSkullwithPattern I'm in the similar situation now, so what advice did you end up doing? And what was the outcome? Did `Company A` give you an offer or still went silent? And if it isn't too much to ask what was your final email when you sent it?

Comment: I found these articles helpful: [A Guide to Juggling Multiple Job Offers and Coming Out on Top](https://www.themuse.com/advice/a-guide-to-juggling-multiple-job-offers-and-coming-out-on-top) [What to do when you get a job offer from your 2nd choice](http://www.prepary.com/job-offer-from-your-2nd-choice-company/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question that would guide your decision is, would you be prepared to take one of the other jobs?  If the answer is yes, then you have little to lose by enquiring and informing them that you have other offers on the table.

However, it can force a decision *either* way, so be prepared for a rejection or even more delays. Do not jeopardize the offers you have if one is not forthcoming from your preferred employer. Take it before it expires and you end up with NO job!

You should also consider, if they are slow in the recruitment process, what else could they be difficult in other areas. What could they be like to work for?

Comment: The only thing I would add is that it might be better to call them rather than communicate by email. If this is your preferred role you wouldn't want to miss it because someone wasn't in the office this afternoon and didn't pick up an email.

Comment: I agree with you. Calling is wise :)

Comment: @JaneS and Dustybin80 Oh my this is so true! Delay on receiving a pay cheque would be awful. Anyway thank you. Yeah I e-mailed them tomorrow morning (Fri) with a more subtle e-mail asking if they're able to provide me an answer before the deadline.

If they still haven't replied, I probably will call the HR right away. Thanks heaps both of you!

Answer (score 9):

I just wanted to add in my two cents from my own experience. I was offered two positions and was awaiting the official call to see if I had the actual job. Both jobs were a great choice, but I was leaning towards company A over company B based more on location.

Well, company B called me with the official job offer. Before accepting, I emailed company A's HR stating that I had been offered the job, and that I needed a status update before the next day (which is when company B needed their answer). Turns out, that while company A did want to hire me, their hiring process probably wouldn't have been complete for another 3 to 4 months. I absolutely could not have waited that long, so I gracefully declined my further candidacy and accepted company B not five minutes later.

The point is, you need to know exactly what's going on. If they want you, they will grab you, if not, you're free to accept one of your other two offers. If they are wishy washy and just want to keep tangling you along, well, do you really want to work for a company that will do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty fair.
You have tried your best at contacting them twice earlier and they still do not reply. If you are so keen on getting the job there put in this mail.

There is nothing wrong in telling the company that you are awaiting their reply. It shows you are interested in their offer and would prefer joining them.
Try calling if possible.

However, if they still do not reply, I feel you should consider the other offers and forget about this or maybe apply in future after sometime of work experience.

Comment: That word, revert, [does not mean what you think it means.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revert?s=t)

Comment: Yes it does https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/revert

Comment: @mattfreake it's been 6 years 

Comment: I was just waiting for the right moment :-) - It actually came up as a suggested edit, replacing "revert" with "reply" so I felt obligated to clarify