# Is it okay to tell the interviewer than I have another job offer

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, human-resources

I have a job offer which I need to respond to within a week. I am interviewing at another organization and cleared first round on Monday.

I emailed to HR of the second organization (as politely as I can)  that I have another job offer and it would be great if overall interview process can be expedited so I can take fair and informed decision.

They did not respond to my request but scheduled next interview tomorrow with a very senior person. If the interview goes well and when they give me opportunity to ask questions, I want to know if it is good idea to tell the interviewer that I have another offer and I am hoping for relatively quick feedback. I am thinking if I tell to the senior executive directly, it might be more impactful in expediting decision.(but could be risky too as it might annoy them).

I have got some insights from [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/46323/is-it-okay-to-tell-the-preferred-company-that-you-have-received-other-job-offers) question but I think situation is different. I want to know if I should tell the interviewer also.

Comment: Don't you think the interviewer would already know? The quick interview with a senior seems a big hint.

Comment: @Kilisi Yes it is possible but also possible that HR scheduled the interview quickly without updating or needing to  update the interviewer. I am not sure how much the interviewer actually has the stake in this role. Also, asking HR what information interviewer has is also bit weird. :-)

Comment: @PagMax Do you think that HR can easily schedule time with senior people.  If the individual is actually senior then something had to be rescheduled to make time for you.  OTH how do you know the "senior person" is really senior?  From what I understand, the lowest level person at the Trump Organization is a senior vice president.

Comment: @emory good point. Yes I do not know they are really senior.  Just going by their linkedin profile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Asking them to make a quick decision might work. It might not. What it does do is potentially speed up the process. The risk is that if they have many good candidates they see no harm is quickly saying no.

Of course if you don't ask, and they take too long then you won't be able to use their offer in your decision process.

> I want to know if I should tell the interviewer also.

Once you informed them that you need a quick decision there is no harm by telling everybody you deal with that you need a quick decision. You don't want to risk that one key person didn't get the memo.

Answer (score 3):

You've already mentioned it and the very senior person most probably knows your situation.

That's valuable information for people who are interested in employing you, but by stressing it too much you're risking being perceived as having unrealistic expectations. They expedited the process for you already, there's not so much they can do apart from that.

I would also be careful not to come to the interview with the attitude "I have one very good offer already so I don't need you anymore. I know my value". I've had graduates doing something like that and me finishing interviews after a few minutes because of that. Everyone knows the rules of the game ("the better option wins - if somebody has an offer, it's probably necessary to offer them more"), but arrogance is never attractive and no one wants to work with unlikable colleagues.

The situation you describe is very common.

Comment: Thanks BigMadAndy. Helpful insight.

Answer (score 1):

For my understanding, you could do that in following scenario:

1. You already finish the current interview, and you mention that for salary negotiation.
2. You just tell the truth, for telling the interview you would like to compare two offers. So they can have a preparation before.
3. You are obvious the best fit for the position, and don't mind your interviewer stop your process. Then you could "push" their progress.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to pressure a potential employer to expedite their interview process likely will not end well for you.  Your request is also a bit unreasonable and I can see them being annoyed with you and dropping you from consideration unless you currently stand out well above any of the other potential candidates.

Just like you, the company would want to make a "fair and informed decision" about any potential candidates.  You need to consider that you are probably not the only person applying for this company.  Should they also expedite the interviews for all of the other candidates to then quickly decide if you are the best one?

If your outstanding offer is good for you then accept it and move on.

Comment: If an employer is interviewing you, and their options really are "move quick, or lose this one", then letting them know that fact is more "providing useful information" rather than "pressuring".  Now, being pushy about it is probably a bad idea, but that's not what the OP is suggesting.

Comment: @sf02 Well what I implicitly mean is "If possible" and I mentioned it explicitly in my email as well.   That is if they cannot expedite for whatever reason, then they can just say so and I have to take my chances.
I agree they could also have too many candidates to interview in which case it is not possible.